# Check if user wasn't logged in after some action

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this task:

> Export a list of customers who created >=1 expense but haven't logged
> into the app for 7 days after the creation (3-9 May)

I need to somehow create a logic which would check if the user wasn't logged in after the time that he created his expense, but I'm pretty much green in SQL, so I don't know the way how this all works. For now I only have created a logic which gets all the users and check for the invoices that were created in the timeline which is 3-9 May.

How can I check if the user wasn't logged in for 7 days.

```
select u.*
from users_user u
where u.completed_registration 
and exists (
   select id
   from operation_operation op
   where op.company_id = u.active_company_id
)
and exists (
   select id
   from invoice_invoice inv
   right join operation_operation op
   on inv.operation_ptr_id = op.id
   and op.created_at between '2021-05-03 00:00:00' and '2021-05-09 00:00:00' /*specify the date of the creation (3-9 May) */
   group by id having count(*) >= 1
)
/* 
How can we check if the user wasn't logged in after the creation for 7days 
we use "u.last_login" for our user last online date 
*/
```

Comment: your query stops at the beginning of 9th of May, was that intended?

Comment: what do you mean? I have to check the creation time of the invoices as this required in the task

Comment: I do mean then invoices created on the 9th of May are not included.

Comment: oh, well I have to check till the 10th day, right? my bad..

Comment: `and u.last_login not between op.created_at and op.created_at + INTERVAL '7 day'` Maybe this could work? But I don't seem any changes when I switch between and & and not

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your query, let me try to explain:

This will select you users with a `u.completed_registration`:

```
select u.*
from users_user u
where u.completed_registration
```

and there must be an `operation_operation` in the `u.active_company_id` NOTE: this  operation_operation might have nothing to do with that user, it can also concern another user of that company!

```
and exists (
   select id
   from operation_operation op
   where op.company_id = u.active_company_id
)
```

and also there must be more than 1 invoice, (but this invoice seems to have no reference to the user?)

```
and exists (
   select id
   from invoice_invoice inv
   right join operation_operation op
   on inv.operation_ptr_id = op.id
   and op.created_at between '2021-05-03 00:00:00' and '2021-05-09 00:00:00' /*specify the date of the creation (3-9 May) */
   group by id having count(*) >= 1
)
```

Comment: hey, but how can I check if the user wasn't logged on for 7days after all of this?